# Makefile implicit rule not working

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have this makefile and i'm trying to write some test targets

```
#This a make file of serial communication driver that i'm writing.
#serial_target would be a target to test this driver isolated.
 
CC = gcc
 
DISPLAY_STRING = -DDISPLAY_STRING
LFLAGS = 
CFLAGS = $(DISPLAY_STRING) 
 
#mains macros
BUILD_DIR =build
SOURCE_DIR =src
HEADER_DIR =src
BIN_DIR =bin
 
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS =  $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
HEADERS =  $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c, $(HEADER_DIR)/%.h, $(SOURCES))
 
 
#serial_tests
TEST_DIR=src/test
TEST_TARGET=serial_test
 
TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*_test.c) \
    $(SOURCES)
TEST_OBJECTS = $(filter %.o ,$(patsubst %.c, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(subst /, , $(TEST_SOURCES))))
TEST_HEADERS = $(TEST_SOURCES:.c=.h)
 
 
all:
    
serial_test: $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $^
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -c $< -o $@     
 
setup:
    mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir $(BIN_DIR)
    
clean:
    rm -rf $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

When running "make serial_test", I'm always getting this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/serial_test.o', needed by `serial_test'. Stop.
```

Here's the doubt. Why I'm receiving this error if the rule $(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o exists?

> Edit

To make sure that everything else was working I've tried this(this works fine)

```
serial_test: $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $^
build/serial_test.o: src/test/serial_test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -c $< -o $@ 
build/serialCom_xsens.o: src/serialCom_xsens.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -c $< -o $@
```

To make sure that the variable BUILD_DIR was note empty i did this:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/serial_test.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(HEADER_DIR) -I$(SOURCE_DIR) -c $< -o $@
```

With this code above, I got another error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `%.c', needed by `build/serial_test.o'. Stop.
```

- Is there any chance of %.c and %.o rules are broken?
- If you have any design tips just answer. That would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're mixing pattern and suffix rules, stick with the pattern rule
- Not entirely sure what you're trying to do with `TEST_OBJECTS`
- You're making every object depend on every header, use dependency generation instead
- The rule for `serial_test` is broken, **always** use `$@` as the output of any given rule
- Make the directories a prerequisite
- Recycle the built-in recipes (`COMPILE.c`, `LINK.o`)

```
display_string := -Ddisplay_string

source_dir := src
header_dir := src
build_dir  := build
bin_dir    := bin
 
sources := $(wildcard $(source_dir)/*.c)
objects := $(sources:$(source_dir)/%.c=$(build_dir)/%.o)
 
test_dir    := src/test
test_target := serial_test
 
test_sources := $(wildcard $(test_dir)/*_test.c)
test_objects := $(test_sources:$(test_dir)/%.c=$(build_dir)/%.o) $(objects)
 
deps := $(test_objects:%.o=%.d)

CPPFLAGS := $(display_string) -I$(header_dir) -MMD -MP
    
$(bin_dir)/serial_test: $(test_objects) | $(bin_dir)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
    
$(build_dir)/%.o: $(source_dir)/%.c | $(build_dir)
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
 
$(build_dir) $(bin_dir): ; mkdir $@
    
clean: ; $(RM) serial_test $(objects) $(deps)

-include $(deps)
```

Comment: I've used TEST_OBJECTS to get a list of all test objects. Probably this was not the best design for my purpose, but what I were trying to do was a makefile(with two main rules, one for the real project executable and another for the tests).
I struggled on the "file tree organization". If you have any makefile design book(or site) I would appreciate.

Comment: @PescadorParrudo read through the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) at least once, the [maintainer](http://make.mad-scientist.net/) also has some good info in the papers and musings section. Beware of make info online or in books, a lot of it is outdated because very few people are using plain make nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Take a hard look at your pattern rule:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
```

It matches filenames with a `.c.o` extension. The error message indicates that you're trying to build `build/serial_test.o`, which doesn't match the pattern because the path doesn't end in `.c.o`.

Fix your pattern in your build rule, or your `patsubst` to replace `.c` with `.c.o`, so that the pattern rule will match.

Comment: `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` I did this, but I'm getting the same result.
> This was my original rule, but I've changed because I saw someone using %.c.o on some site

Comment: @PescadorParrudo, `%.c.o` looks like a bogus amalgamation of a pattern rule and a suffix rule.  That "someone used it on some other site" is not much relevant.  It looks like a pattern rule is what you really want, and in that case the appropriate target is almost certainly `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o`.

Comment: `%.c.o` Creates an .o file from .c one(according to manual). I tried this `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o`  and got stuck in the same error.